# Swift Core Data fetch data 1 column

Tags: swift, core-data

I cannot fetch data by "name" column. When respone, system print all attribute in People. Help me, thanks.

```
 private func getPeople(product: String) {
        let temp = product
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "People", in: context)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
        fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = true
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product == %@", temp)
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
        do {
            let personList = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [People]

            print(personList)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch only specific properties the `resultType` of the request must be `dictionaryResultType`

```
private func getPeople(product: String) {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "People")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "product == %@", product)
        fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
        do {
            let personList = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [[String:String]]

            print(personList)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```